# how to sort XML data in given order in Python

Tags: python, xml, sorting

Not sure if this is going to be a duplicate question..I have tried to find a related answer but not quite found it..here I go..

Here is what I have in XML format data

```
<item>
<title>level red</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level green</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level yellow</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level red</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level yellow</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level red</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level green</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>

<item>
<title>level black</title>
<link>something</link>
<item>
```

My aim is to sort this data in a where  level red first and level green and level yellow comes in the xml list and the rest of level stays whatever..

My question is how do I approach this with Python?

I know I might have to use

```
dom =  xml.dom.minidom.parseString(stripTags(data))
items = dom.getElementsByTagName('item')

item.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes
item.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes
```

I have also seen code like this to sort in order

```
sorted_b = []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if j.id == i:
            sorted_b.append(j)
            break
```

My problem is how do I put the code together and later how i sort the data in my given order of color priority?

Any suggestion or direction is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The Python sorted() function might come in handy:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

especially with the key=... argument.
Try something like

```
def getItemLevel(item):
  return item.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].data

newlist = sorted(itemlist, key=getItemLevel)
```

Comment: I kind of understand little bit but could not figure out how I specify the range such as Red, Green, Yellow..whichever exist will follow the order...